# Convergence in Probability of a sequence whose variance is going to 0

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_n \ge 0$ be a sequence of random variables (which are not necessarily independent) satisfying the following conditions:

- $E(X_n) = \mu_n$ where $l \le \mu_n \le u$ for some constants $l, u < \infty$ (but we don't know whether $\mu_n$ converges to a constant).
- $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} V(X_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow
     \infty$.

By Chebyshev's inequality, we know that $|X_n - \mu_n| \rightarrow 0$ in probability.

Can we say something probabilistic about $X_n$ being in the interval $[l,u]$ with high probability?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I've erased a part where I asked whether we can say $X_n \rightarrow \xi$ for $\xi \in [l,u]$, which is not true, as per saz's comment.

Comment: No, in general we cannot expect this. Just fix any sequence $(\mu_n)_n \subseteq (u,l) \subseteq (0,\infty)$ and set $$X_n(\omega) := \mu_n, \qquad \omega \in \Omega.$$ Then all assumptions are satisfied, but $X_n \to \mu \in (u,l)$ in probability does, in general, not hold true.

Comment: Thanks for your comment -- you're absolutely right. Do you think there is any hope we can say something probabilistic about $X_n$ being in the interval $[l,u]$?

Comment: Not in $[l,u]$ but in every $[l-\varepsilon,u+\varepsilon]$, yes.

Comment: Let's see: I guess this is because if $A_n = \{ |X_n-\mu_n| > \varepsilon \}$ and $B_n = \{ X_n > u+\varepsilon\} \cup \{X_n < l-\varepsilon \}$, we have $B_n \subset A_n$, so $P(B_n) \le P(A_n) \rightarrow 0$.